# Watir, How can i fetch the errors it displays after running a test script and place it on a file

Tags: ruby, watir, scite

Im new to watir and running scripts from it. Just want to ask if how can I get or extract the error messages Scite displays on the left panel and import it to a textfile? or is it really possible to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how would you do it from Scite, but if you execute Watir script from command line, you can redirect output to file:

```
$ ruby watir_script.rb > results.txt
```

If you use test framework like [RSpec](http://rspec.info/), there are a lot of options for storing test results in files.

Answer (score 1):

From Scite, you click in the output frame, Ctrl-A (to select all), Ctrl-C (to copy), then paste into what every application you like such as notepad.

I agree with Zeljko, you should use a good framework like rspec or testunit. Goodluck.